# Connecting postgresql with ballerina

Tags: database, postgresql, ballerina

I am trying to connect a PostgreSQL database using it.  I have the following code:

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerinax/java.jdbc;
import ballerina/sql;

public function main() {
    io:println("Hola mundo");

    jdbc:Client|sql:Error dbClient = 
        new("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/GenteDB","gente","GenteDB123!");

    io:println(dbClient);

    sql:ExecutionResult result = 
            check dbClient->execute(`CREATE TABLE student (
                                       id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                       age INT, 
                                       name VARCHAR(255), 
                                       PRIMARY KEY (id)
                                     )`);

}
```

This doesn't compile and I get the following error:

> ERROR [main.bal:(13:23,18:45)] invalid remote method call: expected a client object, but found '(ballerinax/java.jdbc:1.4.1:Client|ballerina/sql:1.4.1:Error)'

Unfortunately, documentation is scarce, google turned up exactly 0 results for this error message (a first in my lifetime). The line with the error (check dbClient->execute...) was copied directly from ballerina's JDBC driver GitHub page. I have no idea what this error means. What am I missing? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to understand Ballerina's error handling. That might be radically different what you have used to. A good starting point is https://ballerina.io/learn/language-basics/#error-reporting If you want to "ignore" Ballerina errors you have to write "ignoring" code explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of Ballerina Error Handling is different from other languages, For more details on error handling see [Ballerina By Example: Error Handling](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/error-handling/).

To look into this specific case. When invoking `execute()` method `dbClient` may be either `jdbc:Client` or `sql:Error`. You can call the remote method only if the variable is of type `jdbc:Client`. You should narrow the type of the `dbClient` before the remote method is invoked.

```
if dbClient is error {
    // handle the error
} else {
    // Type of `dbClient` will be `jdbc:Client` here.
    sql:ExecutionResult result = 
                check dbClient->execute(`...`);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use check keyword to narrow the type as `sql:Error` is an error type in Ballerina.

```
jdbc:Client dbClient = check new("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/GenteDB","gente","GenteDB123!");
```

For more details on handling errors with check expression see [Ballerina By Example: Check Expression](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/check-expression/).

Do note, the check with return the error. Here, the main function needs to be updated as follows,

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerinax/java.jdbc;
import ballerina/sql;

public function main() returns error? {
    io:println("Hola mundo");

    jdbc:Client dbClient = check new("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/GenteDB","gente","GenteDB123!");

    io:println(dbClient);

    sql:ExecutionResult result = 
        check dbClient->execute(`CREATE TABLE student (
                                   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                   age INT, 
                                   name VARCHAR(255), 
                                   PRIMARY KEY (id)
                                 )`);

}
```